# Post form only after submit using Entity Framework controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have this view that I created so that a user can fill out this form, hit submit, and it will post to a controller that schedules the game. The controller will then return the results of the request.

But I think I may have something missing.  Because when I navigate to the page, via this link:

```
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Schedule" asp-action="CreateGamingEvent">Create Game Schedule</a></li>
```

I think it's trying to post right away, and everything is null or empty and throws errors stating such.

But I don't want it to post until after the user hits submit.

Is there a way to get the form/controller to not try and post until the user is done filling out the form?

Here is the view:

```
@model GameScheduler.Models.gameSchedulingEvent

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateGamingEvent";
}

<h2>CreateGamingEvent</h2>

<h4>gameSchedulingEvent</h4>
<hr />
<div>
    <div>
        <form asp-action="CreateGamingEvent">
            <div>
                <label asp-for="GameName"></label>
                <input asp-for="GameName" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label asp-for="GameStart"></label>
                <input asp-for="GameStart" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label asp-for="GameEnd"></label>
                <input asp-for="GameEnd" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateGamingEvent(
            [Bind("GameName, GameStart, GameEnd")]
    GameSchedulingEvent gameSchedulingEvent)
{
    result = await client.ScheduleAsync(
                gameSchedulingEvent.Name,
                gameSchedulingEvent.Start,
                gameSchedulingEvent.End);

    return View(result);
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you declared the form's action `[HttpPost]`? If not, the default GET will execute when the action link is clicked.

Comment: Yes, when I had [HttpPost] in there, it could not find the page whenever I would try and navigate to it.

Comment: Then you need to split the action so there is a `[HttpGet]` and a `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: You mean I need an HttpGet and HttpPost with the same method name?  thanks

Comment: The name will need to match the request. But yes, the action name can be the same.

Comment: But it's just a form the user fills out, then it should hit the controller when the user hits the submit button.  Why would I need an HttpGet? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action link will send a GET request. You can handle both verbs with two separate actions.

The GET to render the initial form

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateGamingEvent()
{
    return View();
}
```

And POST to accept the form submission

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateGamingEvent(
        [Bind("GameName, GameStart, GameEnd")]
GameSchedulingEvent)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks.  how does this work with .net core entity framework?  Because for each controller method, I need to add a different view.  With HttpGet, would I send them to the form view?  Then what would the HttpPost be for? Thanks again

Comment: EF does not affect this issue. The form submission will send a POST request (unless you specify otherwise) -- so you need the POST action to accept the submission. The returned response from the POST action would depend on your application behavior and if you're using AJAX. See https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/ for a standard response that doesn't involve AJAX.

Comment: I should also clarify: the default form method will be GET if not specified. You ought to use POST if you are changing state i.e. saving a database record.